# Refresh checkboxinput control

Tags: r, shiny

I have a check box control defined in my UI which is reading excel files from a directory and displaying for loading. User selects the file and there is a function defined which loads its data into data frame.

Issue i am facing is that once application starts any addition/deletion of files in the directory is not reflected into checkbox i.e. files read at the start of application are always displayed.
Kindly share any solution.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible option. We use `invalidateLater(1000)` to invalidate the observer every second, and we use a reactiveVal to keep track of the files currently as choices in the selectInput, so we only re-render the input if the files have changed. Hope this helps!

---

### [image]

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('input1','Files: ', NULL)
)

server <- function(input,output, session)
{
  # To keep track of current files
  prev.files<-reactiveVal(NULL)

  observe({
    invalidateLater(1000)
    isolate({
      new_files <- list.files()
      # If files have changed...
      if(!isTRUE(all.equal(new_files,prev.files())))
      {
        print('Updating selectInput')
        updateSelectInput(session,'input1',choices=new_files) # update selectInput
        prev.files(new_files) # Update prev.files()
      }
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: I think using `reactiveFileReader` as its covers this functionality https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveFileReader.html

Comment: @PorkChop, looks promising, I wa sunaware of that function so thanks for sharing. But it seems that its purpose is to automatically invalidate the contents of a single file, not of a folder? I just tried `fileData <- reactiveFileReader(1000, session, '', list.files)` but that does not work.